# How do I return value modified by an AFTER INSERT trigger in Knex.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, knex.js

I want to get back a value after I insert my data

```
const data = {name: "Christmas Shirt 1", price: 5.99, sku: "20210911S", warehouse_id: 2}

const skuCode = await query.returning(['sku_code'], {includeTriggerModifications:true}).insert(data);

console.log(skuCode) // ["20210911-NY"];
```

However, the table that I'm inserting into has an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that will append a prefix to the `sku_code` field:

```
CREATE TRIGGER inventory_trigger
ON inventory AFTER TRIGGER AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE t
  SET sku_code = CASE t.warehouse_id
    WHEN 1 THEN t.sku_code + "NV"
    WHEN 2 THEN t.sku_code + "NY"
  END
  FROM inventory t
  JOIN inserted i ON t.id = i.id
END
```

Is there a way for me to get the value after the `AFTER INSERT` trigger using Knex's `returning()`? I know I can add similar logic in my JS code that manually prepends the prefix but I don't want to duplicate the logic.

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't be using triggers at all, instead create a computed column `ALTER TABLE inventory_trigger ADD SkuWithWarehouse AS CONCAT(sku_code, CASE warehouse_id WHEN 1 THEN 'NV' WHEN 2 THEN 'NY' END);` then `returning()` should work on that column

Comment: And when t.warehouse_id is neither 1 nor 2 (because a "new" warehouse was added), what do you expect to happen and what does happen?